# Loop ends, but doesn't

Tags: java, android, while-loop

I have a while loop that adds elements read using a Buffered Reader to an ArrayList. The loop works fine, except after it finishes, the app doesn't seem to move on. The relevant code is:

```
            int ctr = 1;
            while((test = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {

                Log.i(TAG, test);
                users.add(test);
                Log.i(TAG, "" + (ctr++));

            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Loop done.");
```

The two log statements in the loop execute 4 times each, which is normal behavior. However, the statement after the loop doesn't execute. It's like it gets stuck. I'm pretty sure it doesn't go into the loop either, as the two log statements inside don't execute anymore either.

bf is the BufferedReader, users is the ArrayList.

LogCat Output:

```
08-04 01:35:37.472: I/UM(2937):     UserInfo{0:Primary:3}
08-04 01:35:37.472: I/UM(2937): 1
08-04 01:35:37.476: I/UM(2937):     UserInfo{1:Test1:0}
08-04 01:35:37.476: I/UM(2937): 2
08-04 01:35:37.476: I/UM(2937):     UserInfo{2:test2:0}
08-04 01:35:37.480: I/UM(2937): 3
08-04 01:35:37.480: I/UM(2937):     UserInfo{3:testxyz:0}
08-04 01:35:37.480: I/UM(2937): 4
```

Does anybody have any idea what my (probably stupid) mistake is?

Comment: Can you include the log statements? Also, you say that "The two log statements in the loop execute 4 times each" and "the two log statements inside don't execute" -- which is it?

Comment: I mean, they execute 4 times as expected, and don't execute more than 4 times, which makes me believe that the loop doesn't run anymore

Comment: When you stepped through the code using the debugger, what did you find?

Comment: What is the BufferedReader reading from?  It may be blocking (but not have actually ended).

Comment: Is it possible the `readLine()` method is blocking waiting for more input?

Comment: @Izkata The bufferedReader is reading from the console. I'm executing shell commands

Comment: @RaghavSood Then I expect it will never end...  Try hitting Control-D.

Comment: @Raghav, sounds like you need to send the EOF character after you are done sending the strings.

Comment: @RaghavSood Then it's what Rob said, it's waiting for more input. Type Ctrl+D (on Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Windows) to signal end of input.

Comment: It's directly running on the phone, detached from computers. But I agree with you people. I'll find a way to close the buffered reader after it's done.

Comment: If that's it, one of you should post that as the answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I executed an exit command immediately after the previous command, so it no longer wants input. Lesson: If you code at 2AM, keep coffee around. Thanks everyone.

Comment: And yeah, if someone'll post the solution as an answer, then I'll accept it. I'll wait for a bit, then post it myself. Don't like cluttering up the unanswered tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect it's the condition:

```
while((test = bf.readLine()) != null)
```

Think of it this way:

```
Console ("line1\nline2\n")
---->  BufferedReader ("line1\n", "line2\n")
---->  bf.readline() ("line1\n")
---->  bf.readline() ("line2\n")
```

Your condition is checking for when Console closes its connection entirely, at which point BufferedReader will notice and return `null`.

What's actually happening is that Console's connection to BufferedReader is still open.  BufferedReader is waiting for another `\n` to get passed in from the Console before `readLine()` will return "line3\n".

Answer (score 3):

your code is blocking on the line :

```
 while((test = bf.readLine()) != null)
```

And it is doing so because the stream supplying data to `bf` is never being closed.

(This answer is not mine, its just a quick summary from the comments.)

Comment: If Izkata doesn't post within a few minutes, I'll accept this. Preference goes to that one as he provided the solution first.